# Client-Side Verification Django

Tags: python, html, django, web, server

I'm new to Django and I made a form that extends UserCreationForm and I want to verify the inputs on the client-side. How can I do that? When I validate password1 it works perfectly but for some reason I can't check if the fields are missing. Thanks in advance.

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


    def validate(self,password):

        return self.short_enough(password) and self.has_lowercase(password) and self.has_uppercase(password) and self.has_numeric(password) and self.has_special(password)


    def short_enough(self,pw):
         return len(pw) == 8

    def has_lowercase(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a lowercase letter'
        return len(set(string.ascii_lowercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_uppercase(self,pw):
        'Password must contain an uppercase letter'
        return len(set(string.ascii_uppercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_numeric(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a digit'
        return len(set(string.digits).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_special(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a special character'
        return len(set(string.punctuation).intersection(pw)) > 0


    def clean(self):
        
        cleaned_data = super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean()

        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if username == None or email == None or password1 == None or password2 == None:      
              raise forms.ValidationError("Some fields are missing" )
              

        if not self.validate(password1):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be 8 characters(1 upper, 1 lower, 1 number, 1 special character)" )
        else:
            return cleaned_data
```

And this is my HTML File, the thing is that I'm using {{ form }} not HTML inputs:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">

        <form method="POST" >

            {% csrf_token %}

            <fieldset class="form-group" aria-required="true">

                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Join Today </legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}

            </fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">

                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" > Sign Up </button>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div class="border-top pt-3">
             <small class="text-muted">

             Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}" >Sign In</a>

            </small> 
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Hi there, django does not provide any client side validation, you should program it using javascript (take in mind that some html5 tags provides you some validations out of the box), once you create your js file, use form.Media (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/media/) to include that file in your template

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but are you sure of that? I made my own rules for the password in the clean(self) method and it works, but I can't validate the inputs if they're empty or not

Comment: So you are making a validation in your server side :) you can add the required=True param to your form fields to take care of this automatically, if True, it will not allow empty values and in browsers that supports html5 tags, the form will not be posted if empty throwing a message to the user, check it out and let me know

Comment: I'' post my html file so you can check it out, I used {{ form }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your template looks good, just some additions in you form.

To simplify the code I added `required=True` to your defined email field and set the same param into the `__init__` method for the rest of the fields, this will do all fields as required, you can get rid of your custom "empty values" validation in `clean`

```py
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].required = True
        self.fields['password1'].required = True
        self.fields['password2'].required = True

    def validate(self,password):

        return self.short_enough(password) and self.has_lowercase(password) and self.has_uppercase(password) and self.has_numeric(password) and self.has_special(password)


    def short_enough(self,pw):
         return len(pw) == 8

    def has_lowercase(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a lowercase letter'
        return len(set(string.ascii_lowercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_uppercase(self,pw):
        'Password must contain an uppercase letter'
        return len(set(string.ascii_uppercase).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_numeric(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a digit'
        return len(set(string.digits).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def has_special(self,pw):
        'Password must contain a special character'
        return len(set(string.punctuation).intersection(pw)) > 0

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")          

        if not self.validate(password1):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be 8 characters(1 upper, 1 lower, 1 number, 1 special character)" )
        else:
            return cleaned_data
```

---

On the other hand, to make single field validations, I suggest you to user django provided methods `clean_<fieldname>`, check the docs here --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

As you are using django crispy forms, you can include your submit button in your form definition as well as the form tags, it will encapsulate all form DOM in you python code, which I think it's great, check the docs --> https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html

Comment: thank you!, if I want to compare also the 2 passwords if they are matched DO I have to added the condition in validate()?

Comment: yeah, you can do it as you do the rest of validations

Comment: But I suggest you to get rid of your custom `validate` method since it is redundant with the default `clean`, just move the the code from `validate` to `clean` IMOO

Comment: the thing is that I'm asked to make validations on the client side, can I prevent the django default validation for the 2 passwords?

Comment: There's a setting to set the password validators to run, check the docs --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation this should be the way